# Siding cookie expiration

Tags: http, cookies

Is it possible for cookies to have a sliding expiration or do you have to reset the cookie with a new absolute expiration date on every request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sliding you mean relative to that last time it was sent to the server?  No, cookie expiration doesn't work that way, but you could implement in javascript on the client or on the server, to reset the expiration whenever to you want, to whatever you want.